# How to adjust a dictionary of datetime.time() values to the return of the datetime.time() input

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

So I have a dictionary of a key and several tuples. Like so,

```py
import datetime

my_dictionary = {'a': (datetime.time(9), datetime.time(10)), 'b': (datetime.time(11), datetime.time(12))}

print(my_dictionary)

my_time = {}

for a in my_dictionary:
    time = my_dictionary[a]
    my_time[a] = time

print(f"Time: {my_time}")
```

I am wanting to replace the datetime.time() methods with their numerical return value into the new dictionary  `my_time ={}` I was trying to do this iteratively with the for loop, but I am not sure how to do this correctly. With the information above I would expect to get the output:

```py
{'a': (09:00:00, 10:00:00), 'b': (11:00:00, 12:00:00)}
```

Comment: Change `datetime.time(...)` to `str(datetime.time(...))` ?

Comment: This could be one way, but I really need them to be numerical because I need to compare the first time value for each key further down the project.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "numerical"? `09:00:00` is not a valid Python object. The closest you can get is the string `'09:00:00'` which my comment provides you.

Comment: If you need to do "time" calculations later in your code, leave the `time` objects as they are.

Comment: Okay, so down the line I plan on comparing the first time value , a, to the first time value of , b. What would be the best way to do this if I wanted to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you even try before asking? For example, what `print(datetime.time(9) < datetime.time(10))` gives you?

Comment: No, I am new to python and did not think you could compare them like that. I will try and see what that does for me. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: I see why this works. I do not know why I did not think of this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`X:00:00` is the string representation of `datetime.time(X)`.

In-place:

```
my_dictionary = {'a': (str(datetime.time(9)), str(datetime.time(10))), 'b': (str(datetime.time(11)), str(datetime.time(12)))}
```

After the creation of `my_dictionary`:

```
my_dictionary = {'a': (datetime.time(9), datetime.time(10)), 'b': (datetime.time(11), datetime.time(12))}
my_time = {k: tuple(map(str, v)) for k, v in my_dictionary.items()}
```